# Number of digits in MNIST data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, mnist, anaconda3

How can I find the number of samples per digit in training and test sets? Also if I want to >visualize at least 9 images for each digit in the training data.
#Loading MNIST data set in Python

````
   no_of_different_labels = 10
   image_pixels = image_size * image_size```

#Loading Training Samples

```train_data = np.loadtxt("mnist_train.csv", delimiter=",")
X_train = train_data[:,1:]
t_train = train_data[:,0]```

#Loading Test Samples

```test_data = np.loadtxt("mnist_test.csv", delimiter=",")` 
X_test = test_data[:,1:]
t_test = test_data[:,0]```


Question: How can I find the number of samples per digit in training and test sets? Also if I want to >visualize at least 9 images for each digit in the training data.
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Numpy's `unique` function, and zip both the resulting numbers and counts into a dictionary that indicates the digit counts:

```py
# y_train is the same as your t_train. It's usual to name label arrays with "y" :-)

# Count elements, and return unique numbers and their counts
unique, counts = np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True)
>>> dict(zip(unique, counts))
{0.0: 5923, 1.0: 6742, 2.0: 5958, 3.0: 6131, 4.0: 5842, 5.0: 5421, 6.0: 5918, 7.0: 6265, 8.0: 5851, 9.0: 5949}

# The same goes for the test set!
```

Furthermore, if you want to visualize some images for each digit, you can use Python's amazing `matplotlib` library :-)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Reshape digits into 28x28 for Matplotlib to properly print them
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000,28,28)

# Create a 2D grid of subfigures
fig, axes = plt.subplots(10, 9, figsize=(15,18))

# i is the digit iterator. j is the samples-per-digit iterator
for i in range(10):
    # Select digits that equal "i"
    digits = X_train[y_train == i]
    for j in range(9):
        # Select axis, and print the digit on it!
        ax = axes[i, j]
        ax.imshow(digits[j], cmap="gray")

# This will give you the visualization :-)
plt.show()
```

I hope this is helpful. Cheers!